# Flipping Coins in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a GUI program in Java. The GUI consists of 9 buttons titled H. In run mode, when the mouse clicks on any button, that button should change the heading to T. I have a `MouseListener` code watching out for the clicks. But I have no way of finding out based on the mouse clicks that I need to change that particular button. Any help is appreciated.
Below is my code.

```
package flippingcoins;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FlippingCoins extends JFrame
{
    public FlippingCoins()
    {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,1,1));

        JButton jbt1=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt1);
        JButton jbt2=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt2);
        JButton jbt3=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt3);
        JButton jbt4=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt4);
        JButton jbt5=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt5);
        JButton jbt6=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt6);
        JButton jbt7=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt7);
        JButton jbt8=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt8);
        JButton jbt9=new JButton("H");
        p.add(jbt9);
        add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) //Main program begins here.
    {
        FlippingCoins frame = new FlippingCoins();//Instantiating an object.
        frame.setTitle("Head or Tails");//Setting the frame title.
        frame.setSize(300,300);//Setting the size.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Setting the location.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);// Default closing options.
        frame.setVisible(true);//Setting visibility to true.
    }//End of main program.

    static class ChangeTiles extends JPanel
    {
        public ChangeTiles()
        {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()//Creating a listener
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)//When the mouse is clicked.
            {
              int x=e.getX();
              int y=e.getY();
              System.out.println("x= "+ x + "y= "+y);

            }
        }
                        ); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public FlippingCoins() {
    final JPanel p = new JPanel();

    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 1, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        final JButton jbt = new JButton("H");
        jbt.setName("" + i);
        jbt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                jbt.setText("T");
                System.out.println(jbt.getName());
            }
        });
        p.add(jbt);
    }
    setContentPane(p);
}
```

Some notes:

- use *loops* for repetitive tasks
- listeners have to be *added* to the widget they should listen to
- do not use `MouseListener`s for `JButton`, there is `ActionListener`

**Alternative for `JLabel`**:

```
public FlippingCoins2() {
    final JPanel p = new JPanel();

    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 1, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        final JLabel jlb = new JLabel("H", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jlb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        jlb.setName("" + i);
        jlb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
                jlb.setText("T");
                System.out.println(jlb.getName());
            }
        });
        p.add(jlb);
    }
    setContentPane(p);
}
```

Comment: What if I am required to use the mouse listener? I am not required to use the jbutton. I could use labels also with lines dividing the frame.

Comment: @user2918968: I modified the example for your requirement.

Comment: Jens Piegsa... Thank you very much for your help. It works perfect.

Answer (score 5):

That's not the good strategy. Instead, add an `ActionListener` to every button. Not only will it be much easier, but users will then also be able to use their keyboard to click the buttons.

Also, consider using an array or list of buttons. That will allow using loops instead of copying and pasting the same code 9 times.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it:

```
JButton jbt1=new JButton("H");
jbt1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
//add ButtonListener to all of the other buttons

//Somewhere in your code:
public class ButtonListener extends ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
        source.setText("T");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be easy if you add an ActionListener. Inside the actionPerformed code you can make it print out which button was clicked.

```
getSource()

Returns: The object on which the Event initially occurred.
```

you can call getSource() on the ActionEvent generated by the ActionPerformed method. I haven't tried this but sounds like you can easily find out which button was clicked.

Comment: Don't forget to cast it to JButton